# Android recyclerView: how to retain the selectableItemBackground to keep the row highlighted?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-drawable

I am successfully able to show a ripple effect on click of a recycler view item by setting this to the row:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:focusable="true"
```

When clicked, I am presenting a detail activity. How can I retain the ripple effect background when clicked? i.e. when a cell is clicked, the ripple animation occurs. I want the ripple to stay there after competition I manually remove it (when I return back to this activity). Sort of like keeping that row highlighted until I remove the highlight. How can I achieve this?

I tried setting `focusableInTouchMode` to true for the row and this does keep the row highlighted but then the `onClick` never gets called.

Comment: you can highlight it additionally. something like: add parameter isClicked to your row item change it by click and teach RV adapter to highlight row with isClciked==true. and clean it inside onResume for example - to remove highlighting after you will back